# Looping php array to json prints index value

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I have been trying to loop through an array. Inserting the values in two separate arrays $location and $name. But the $name array prints the index values as well, the $location works fine.
Here's a sample of code

```
$j = 0;
foreach( $entities->results as $key => $value ) {

    if( stristr($value->vicinity, $key_stroke) ) {

        $location[$j]['place_id'] = $value->place_id;
        $location[$j]['vicinity'] = $value->vicinity;
    }

    if( stristr($value->name, $key_stroke) ) {

        $name[$j]['place_id'] = $value->place_id;
        $name[$j]['name'] = $value->name;
    }


 $j++; }
```

Here is the json output

```
{
    "locations": [
        {
            "place_id": "ChIJRQqyYRFZWjcRmxKd0esyj-k",
            "vicinity": "GS Road, Christian Basti, Guwahati"
        },
        {
            "place_id": "ChIJG5IvxhNZWjcRlkMD6lCJ64c",
            "vicinity": "GS Road, Ananda Nagar, Christian Basti, Guwahati"
        },
        {
            "place_id": "ChIJxQp72BZZWjcR98oQbFrdTII",
            "vicinity": "GS Road, Christian Basti, Guwahati"
        },
        {
            "place_id": "ChIJm5eeJBBZWjcRksI_VY9u1Qo",
            "vicinity": "Zoo Road, Sundarpur, Guwahati"
        }
    ],
    "names": {
        "1": {
            "place_id": "ChIJG5IvxhNZWjcRlkMD6lCJ64c",
            "name": "Ayush Medico's"
        },
        "2": {
            "place_id": "ChIJxQp72BZZWjcR98oQbFrdTII",
            "name": "Premananda Medico's"
        },
        "3": {
            "place_id": "ChIJm5eeJBBZWjcRksI_VY9u1Qo",
            "name": "Asaan Medicos"
        }
    }
}
```

Tried everything. What could be the problem??

Comment: Your if statement `if( stristr($value->name, $key_stroke) )` seem to return false on the first iteration, which makes it omit the 0 index.  When converting to json, that will make the "array" into an object instead since arrays can't have any gaps in the indexes.

Comment: When you combine the results, use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php), to reset the indexes and it be fine.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it worked man..thanks a lot....but i have no idea what it just did. Would you mind explaining?? Please

Comment: @MagnusEriksson explained it and the docs explain array_values - returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks alot...

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: (Not efficient as the solution 2 below)

```
$j = 0;
$i = 0; // change over here
foreach( $entities->results as $key => $value ) {

    if( stristr($value->vicinity, $key_stroke) ) {

        $location[$j]['place_id'] = $value->place_id;
        $location[$j]['vicinity'] = $value->vicinity;
        $j++;
    }

    if( stristr($value->name, $key_stroke) ) {

        $name[$i]['place_id'] = $value->place_id; // change over here
        $name[$i]['name'] = $value->name;         // change over here
        $i++;
    }

}
```

Solution 2:

Pass the `$name` array to php's inbuilt funtion `array_values()` which in turn will return you with the array index starting from `0`.

Comment: The first solution still encodes `$location` as object in JSON if the first `if` condition is `false` for some `$value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely you will notice that in JSON, the value of `"location"` is an array but the value of `"names"` is an object (having the properties `"1"`, `"2"` and `"3"`). This happens because `$location` is an array that contains `4` values associated with the keys `0`, `1`, `2` and `3` while `$name` is an array whose keys are `1`, `2` and `3`.

Because JSON is a subset of JavaScript and JavaScript arrays allow only numeric keys (starting from `0`), PHP encodes as JavaScript arrays only the arrays that have numeric consecutive keys starting from `0`. All the other arrays are encoded in JSON as objects.

This is written in the [documentation of `json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-notes):

> **Note:**
>
> When encoding an array, if the keys are not a continuous numeric sequence starting from `0`, all keys are encoded as strings, and specified explicitly for each key-value pair.

The reason why `$names` does not contain the key `0` is the `if` condition that wraps the assignment:

```
if( stristr($value->name, $key_stroke) ) {
```

The similar condition that wraps the assignment of `$location[$j]` can make `$location` behave similar with different input data.

If you want to get arrays in the JSON-encoded output you have to build them in a way that ensures the keys are consecutive integers starting with `0`. This is easier than it sounds. There is no need to keep track of the keys, just build the inner arrays in a different way and let PHP [generate the keys](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) of the outer arrays:

```
$location = array();
$name     = array();

foreach( $entities->results as $key => $value ) {

    if( stristr($value->vicinity, $key_stroke) ) {

        $location[] = array(
           'place_id' => $value->place_id,
           'vicinity' => $value->vicinity,
        );
    }

    if( stristr($value->name, $key_stroke) ) {

        $name[] = array(
            'place_id' => $value->place_id,
            'name'     => $value->name,
        );
    }
}
```